# Time calculation giving increasingly wrong result

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I need to create a Timer that counts down from a string I get from the server. the string outputs total seconds left.

I am using this code - it calculates the initial number time right and it counts down but the minutes are the problem.

EDIT - Every real minute the minute calculation goes up by one. But I don't understand why it is doing this.

-(void)showTimmer:(id) sender {

```
//get total amount of seconds

NSString *timeRaw =  [ArrayFromServer objectAtIndex:1];
NSArray *timeArr = [timeRaw componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
timetoInt =  [timeArr objectAtIndex:0];
int time1 = [timetoInt intValue];

//set the second countdown

NSDate* now = [NSDate date];    
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:now];

NSInteger seconds = time1 - [dateComponents second];

[gregorian release];

// do the hours days maths

int hour = (seconds / 3600 );
seconds -= hour * 3600;
int minute = (seconds / 60 );
seconds -= minute * 60;
int second = seconds;

//set the labels

countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02dH %02dM %02ds", hour, minute, second];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using your pliers to drive a screw. The `seconds` method of an `NSDateComponents` gives you what you would see on a clock if you looked at the second hand at the time represented by your `NSDate`. For example, as I type this, it's UTC Saturday March 26, 2011, 02:52:04. If I got `[NSDate date]`, turned it into an `NSDateComponents` and asked that for its `seconds`, I'd get "4". If I did it again in a second, I'd get "5", and when the minute clicked over, I'd get "59", then "0".

You can verify this for yourself; put this in your timer method:

```
NSInteger dcSecond = [dateComponents second];
NSLog(@"%d", dcSecond);
```

So every time the minute of the actual clock ticks over, your calculation of the remaining time:

```
NSInteger seconds = time1 - [dateComponents second];
```

subtracts `0` from `time1` and gives you back `time1`. That's why you're having the problem.

The way* to fix it is to dump the calendar stuff and use `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()`. First, put the start time in your timer's userInfo (or in an ivar if you prefer):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimer...
        // The function returns CFAbsoluteTime, which is a
        // typedef'd double but you're already working with
        // integers, so use a cast
             userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()]
                ...];
```

Then change your calculation of the remaining time (the variable you call `seconds`:

```
NSInteger startTime = [[timer userInfo] integerValue];
NSInteger currTime = (NSInteger)CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
NSInteger elapsedTime = currTime - startTime;
NSInteger duration = time1 - startTime;
//NSInteger seconds = time1 - [dateComponents second];
NSInteger remaining =  duration - elapsedTime;

int hour = remaining / 3600;
...
```

---

*: Well, *one* way, but I think probably the best.

Comment: Another option would be to save the start time as an `NSDate`, and then you can do `NSInteger elapsedTime = (NSInteger)[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow];`

Comment: This worked perfectly Thank you, amazing how simple it is once you know.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was a rounding error myself until I realized what `NSDateComponents` was doing. The docs on that class and its companions are definitely on the laconic side. (My personal favorite is [`NSCalendar -firstWeekday`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/firstWeekday).) Incidentally, you might try using `double`s, since that's what `CF-` and `NS-``TimeInterval` both are. Then use `fmod`, `ceil` and `floor` as needed. Anyways, glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to subtract the calculated hours from the total amount of seconds before going to the next line (not sure why you use modulo). Something like this (note

```
int hour = (seconds / 3600 );
seconds -= hour * 3600;
int minute = (seconds / 60 );
seconds -= minute * 60;
int second = seconds;
```

Hope that fixes it.

Comment: Nope but i did notice that the problem is that when the minute goes up on the iPhone sim the mintue goes up one! any ideas?

Comment: Doing modulo is a perfectly valid way to do time parsing; you may need to keep the total counter value around.